# Axios get request successful but data attribute empty?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, axios, httpresponse

I have a simple react component:

```
import React from "react"
import axios from "axios"

export default () => {
  const axios = require("axios")

  axios.get("http://localhost:8000/user").then(function(res) {
    // handle success
    console.log(res)
  })

  return (
    <div>
        Hello
    </div>
  )
}
```

I do get something back, with status code 200, and it does console.log, but the data field is empty. It's just `data: ""`; The get request I am making is to my own nodejs server. I should be getting back the currently logged in user. This works when I go visit the URL directly (`localhost:8000/user`). It looks like this

```
"displayName": "thomas",
"id": "google-oauth2|197913719739127391723",
"user_id": "google-oauth2|197913719739127391723",
"name": {
"givenName": "thomas3000"
},
"emails": [
{
"value": "thomas3k@tmail.com"
}
],
"picture": "https://akfaf/afaf/photo.jpg",
"locale": "en",
"nickname": "thomas3000",
"_json": {
"sub": "google-oauth2|197913719739127391723",
"given_name": "thomas3k",
"nickname": "tom",
//... and so on; changed the values here.
```

However, here's the console.log of the axios response:
[image: Response seems ok]

Data Attribute is an empty string. I don't know why I shouldn't be able to get this data in my axios get request?

edit: (request for backend code)

**Backend**

```
//imports here, then:    
passport.use(
  new Auth0Strategy(
    {
      domain: "bla.eu.auth0.com",
      clientID: "afjgnrtkngewmofmwlefmlwems",
      clientSecret:
        "jngnsknkankjangkjangjknKJJKGKAHBJVvgjvVgjVbhJBjhbJbj",
      callbackURL: "http://localhost:8000/callback",
      audience: "https://bla.eu.auth0.com/userinfo",
      responseType: "code",
      scope: "openid email profile",
    },
    function(accessToken, refreshToken, extraParam, profile, done) {
      return done(null, profile)
    }
  )
)

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user)
})

passport.deserializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user)
})

const app = express()
app.use(cors({ origin: "http://localhost:8001" }))

app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

app.use(
  session({ secret: "secret_key", resave: true, saveUninitialized: true })
)

app.use(passport.initialize())
app.use(passport.session())

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.locals.loggeedIn = false
  if (req.session.passport && typeof req.session.passport.user !== undefined) {
    res.locals.loggedIn = true
  }
  next()
})

app.get("/", function(req, res, next) {
  res.send("Root")
})

app.get(
  "/login",
  passport.authenticate(
    "auth0",
    {
      domain: "bla.auth0.com",
      clientID: "kafmkafmkamfkamfka",
      redirectUri: "http://localhost:8000/callback",
      audience: "https://bla.auth0.com/userinfo",
      responseType: "code",
      scope: "openid email profile",
    },
    function(req, res, next) {
      res.redirect("/")
    }
  )
)

app.get("/logout", function(req, res, next) {
  req.logout()
  res.redirect("/")
})

app.get(
  "/callback",
  passport.authenticate("auth0", {
    failureRedirect: "/failure",
  }),
  function(req, res) {
    res.redirect("/user")
  }
)

app.get("/user", function(req, res, next) {
  res.send(req.user)
})

app.get("/failure", function(req, res, next) {
  res.send("Failure")
})

app.listen(8000, function() {
  console.log("running")
})
```

Comment: Why are you importing `axios` twice - with `require` and `import`?

Comment: oh, sorry! but fixed it just now, doesn't change the problem! thanks anyways!

Comment: can you try write this instead and tell me if it works out?
axios.get("http://localhost:8000/user").then(res => {
    // handle success
    console.log(res)
  })

Comment: Do you know how the current user gets determined? Cookies? If you’re getting a 200 can we assume that your API returns an empty response when the user can not be determined?

Comment: oh, so when I visit `8000/user` in my browser, this does not mean that when i make the axios request from my react front-end I can assume I will get the same response?

Comment: can you share your backend code? Your axios.get looks correct if you have no authorization set up to access your /user endpoint

Comment: @A123 thanks for having a look! I have added my backend code to my original post. I'm not very strong on Backend / Node, and am not sure whether my setup is correct, so it might very well be that. I think the problem might have to do with that whenever my axios frontend makes a request to my backend, no user is logged in. So axios is working, but since no user is logged in, `data` will be empty. However, I don't understand why when I visit the endpoint in my browser, I get back my logged in user object : /

Comment: Passport works on middlewares. Meaning if u attach the middle ware than only user get user in request. else it will be empty. I ur code app.get("/user",  doesnt have passport middleware, so user is not there. if u want user in all request u have to enable middleware in all request. like serilizer deserilizer. Please read passport js documentation. it  may help u.

http://www.passportjs.org/docs/username-password/